# Database - The process of editing

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions

I have a table named `tbl_Subjects_Taken` which lists all the subjects taken by the student. It is consists of only two columns, `Stud_ID` and `Subj_ID`.

Going out to the front-end, I have a form that lets the user edit the information about the student itself and the subjects taken by that student. Updating `tbl_Students` (the student's information) is not a problem as a single UPDATE statement can do the work. But what about the other table?

Once the user edited the  form and pressed the save button, here is what I do:

1. Delete all the subjects taken by that student  in  `tbl_Subjects_Taken`.
2. Add all the subjects located  in the form (in my program).

Is this really the right way of updating a table in the "many side"?

I use **SQL server**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting and re-adding is one way to do it.

But I would try to do everything on the server (e.g. use a stored procedure). I would pass in the list of subject IDs to the SP. Inside the SP, I would do the following:

1. Delete any subjects from `tbl_Subjects_Taken` for that user that were **not** in the list that I passed in
2. Add any subjects that weren't in the `tbl_Subjects_Taken` table that **were** in the list I passed in.

You didn't mention your DB, but there are different ways to go about this depending on what DB you are using. In Oracle and ODP.Net, for example, you can use a [PL/SQL Associative array](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-jan/o17odp-093600.html) to pass in the IDs to your PL/SQL function/SP.

But ideally, you want to make one server round trip, and you want to do as few deletes and inserts as possible. Those two steps should result in good efficiency.

Comment: Nice approach, but do you think that mine is fairly acceptable, if I may know?

Comment: @Arman - It depends on many factors. If you are only dealing with a few subjects, maybe your approach is fine. Only you know the answer to that. But with DB applications, you always want to minimize server round trips. Those tend to kill your performance. So I always try to do everything with a single SP call if I can. The beauty of this approach (e.g. using SP for the bulk of your work) is that you are putting key business logic in the DB via the SP, where that business logic can then be reused by other applications.

Comment: Thanks, but for the mean time I will use mine because only few subjects are concerned, but will try what you've said later.